# Is there an already existing i18n time unit list in java?

Tags: java, internationalization, java-7

Java disposes of [`DateFormatSymbols`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) which allows to generate the days of week according to the given locale. Is there the same mecanism for time units (seconds, minutes…) ?

So far, I only found [`java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) and [`java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) which dispose of a list in english. but no localized version.

NB : I'm just interested in features from the "vanilla" java7 (I'd rather create my own system than load a full api)

Comment: i think [this](http://www.joda.org/joda-time-i18n/) is what you need

Comment: @karimmohsen indeed, but it's far too complete for what I need. i updated my question

Comment: can you use Java 8 or do you need Java 7?

Comment: Right now, I need a java7 solution but I am always curious to see new java8 features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java 8 there is `java.time.temporal.ChronoField#getDisplayName(Locale)`

```
Locale fr = Locale.FRENCH;
System.out.println(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY.getDisplayName(fr));
System.out.println(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR.getDisplayName(fr));
System.out.println(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE.getDisplayName(fr));
```

prints

```
heure
minute
seconde
```

Comment: While useful, the question is about ChronoUnit and TimeUnit, not ChronoField. I'm not aware of an easy way to get to ChronoField from ChronoUnit/TimeUnit.

Comment: @Necreaux the OP wants to localize time unit names like "seconds", "minutes", ie. translate them into the language of a locale; fxm states that TimeUnit and ChronoUnit provide a list of english names only and that is not what he wants. So it is about translation and not about specific constants or enums.

Comment: @Necreaux The problem with ChronoFields is that apperently not all of them are localizeable. And some important units are not available, since this enum serves a different purpose. How would you display "3 weeks" using ChronoField? In particular, which ChronoField would you use for that?